# datatool: why does \DTLifstringeq not work in the address part of a bulk letter

Tags: datatool, dinbrief

I'm trying to create a bulk letter using the package dinbrief and datatool. I created the whole letter and except from one problem everything works fine (that's why I don't want to change any major stuff like switching to other packages)

The problem is the command \DTLifstringeq of the datatool-package. Within the letter, this command is working fine, but within the address part of the letter it creates an error. I need this command to distinguish the gender and I'm curious why it is not working as expected.

Below I have a minimal working example of my code and a exemplary csv-file. If you run it unchanged it produces the bulk letter as expected, however, deleting the comment in line 22 with the \DTLifstringeq-command I get an error. Can somebody explain me why?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[separator=;]{datatool}

\address{briefkopf}
\backaddress{backaddress}
\nowindowrules

\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb{addr}{mwe.csv} % open database
\DTLforeach{addr}{%
    \sex=sex,%
    \firstname=firstname,%
    \surname=surname%
}{ % start bulk letter
\begin{letter}{%
    %\DTLifstringeq{\sex}{w}{Frau}{Herr}\\%
    \firstname\ \surname\\
    street No.\\
    ZIP city
    }
\subject{\textbf{subject}}
\opening{\DTLifstringeq{\sex}{w}%
    {Sehr geehrte Frau \firstname\ \surname}%
    {Sehr geehrter Herr \firstname\ \surname}%
    ,}
text
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\end{letter}
} % close bulk letter
\end{document}
```

corresponding csv-data:

```
sex;firstname;surname
m;Thomas;Eddison
w;Anna;Fisher
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address supplied in the argument of the `letter` environment gets split and there seems to be some expansion occurring in this process. If you replace `\DTLifstringeq` with `etoolbox`'s `\ifdefstring` the error will go away, but the title appears incorrectly as it's testing `\w` when it hasn't been updated. It seems the best way of getting around this is to define a robust command to prevent the premature expansion issue:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{dinbrief}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[separator=;]{datatool}

\address{briefkopf}
\backaddress{backaddress}
\nowindowrules

\newrobustcmd{\Title}{\ifdefstring{\sex}{w}{Frau}{Herr}}

\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb{addr}{mwe.csv} % open database
\DTLforeach{addr}{%
    \sex=sex,%
    \firstname=firstname,%
    \surname=surname%
}{ % start bulk letter
\begin{letter}{%
    \Title\\%
    \firstname\ \surname\\
    street No.\\
    ZIP city
    }
\subject{\textbf{subject}}
\opening{\ifdefstring{\sex}{w}%
    {Sehr geehrte Frau \firstname\ \surname}%
    {Sehr geehrter Herr \firstname\ \surname}%
    ,}
text
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
\end{letter}
} % close bulk letter
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: Image of page 1]

on the first page and

[image: Image of page 2]

on the second page.

Comment: wow, thank you, it works perfectly. It's amazing how fast you can get an answer here. And I definitely must read some stuff about robust commands in latex :)